# Can we have multiple attachment sections inside a list item inside our SharePoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, custom-list, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have a custom list inside our SharePoint online site, currently we can add attachments inside the list items under the Attachments section, but my question is if we can using SharePoint or power-app to add multiple sections for the attachments, so we can identify the attachments. Something as follow (where we have Attachment1,Attachment2 & Attachment3 sections under the same item):-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, it is not possible to add multiple attachments columns to a single list.

However, in the attachments of an item is it possible to upload multiple files as attachment.